# $_GET[key] key undefined while giving QUERY_STRING

Tags: php

Here is my info.php script:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

    echo "[";
    echo $_GET["username"];
    echo "]";

    echo "[";
    echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    echo "]";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch the PHP server with this command:

```
php -S localhost:9001
```

and make a request like:
http://localhost:9001/info.php?username=randomname

I get the $username and the QUERY_STRING displayed which is fine

but when I try to launch it from command line with this command

```
QUERY_STRING="username=HELLO" php-cgi info.php
```

I get the QUERY_STRING but not the username and I can't find why, I tried to give the full REQUEST_URI and still does not work.

When I try to set REQUEST_METHOD=GET I get an error pages

I would like to know what am I missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Because when you are running from command line it is not a GET request

Comment: then If i set the REQUEST_METHOD to GET it should be considered as GET request ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? When you're invoking the script from the command line, you're not using an HTTP request.

Comment: I'm making a webserver in c++ I've done all the things to handle GET POST DELETE requets and now I'm trying to implement something to execute a php cgi script, so I'm gonna use php-cgi command giving the right env variable (I'm using execve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executed in web context (CGI, Apache module, fastCGI, web server) the PHP interpreter populates the [superglobal variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `$_GET` with the query string parameters of the HTTP request being processed. The CLI does not populate `$_GET` because it does not process an HTTP request (and a query string does not exist).

The superglobal variable [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is populated by all flavours of the PHP interpreter but with different values from different sources.
In web context, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the query string of the request.
The CLI does not process HTTP requests. It puts the process environment variables in `$_SERVER[]` (amongst other values.)

Because you executed the CLI with the environment variable `QUERY_STRING` set, its value is available to the PHP script in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. However, it does not have any special meaning for the CLI interpreter. It is not parsed and `$_GET` is not populated.

Read about [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Write `<?php phpinfo();` in a new PHP file then open it using the CGI interpreter, the embedded web server or the CLI to find how PHP initializes the superglobals.